# Why does HDFS store data in /tmp by default?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In HDFS:

- a NameNode stores the location of blocks in the folder `dfs.namenode.name.dir`
- DataNode store the actual data blocks in the folder `dfs.datanode.data.dir`

Together, these two properties make up the most important part of HDFS: where your data is saved.

By default:

- `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` are sub-directories inside `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}` (see [`hdfs-default.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml))
- `${hadoop.tmp.dir}` is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}` (see [`core-default.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml))

In short, HDFS stores your data in `/tmp` by default.

[`/tmp` is emptied often](https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared) in modern Linux distros.

Why does HDFS store data in `/tmp` by default? Why would anyone want their data to be temporary?

Answer (score 2):

Because Hadoop makes no assumptions about your file structure, wants to be straightforward to install, and guides users to override those properties upon proper configuration.

Most Linux distros have /tmp, and it's publicly writable by all users. Not sure /etc, /var or /mnt fit that criteria

Obviously no one wants data to be temporary, but the defaults aren't meant to be production ready, either. For example, `fs.defaultFS` is only the local filesystem by default and there's only 1 file replica